# create array of objects from an array of string ids with 1st object having first value with second, second with third and so on

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an array of strings e.g. `const array1 = ["124542", "112244", "112245", "112246"];`

I want to create below results:

```
const array2 = [
  {
    "comparableId": "124542",
    "comparatorId": "112244"
  },
  {
    "comparableId": "112244",
    "comparatorId": "112245"
  },
  {
    "comparableId": "112245",
    "comparatorId": "112246"
  }
]
```

In this array2, 1st index value from array1 is with 2nd value, 2nd value with 3rd and 3rd with 4th and so on. This array1 is dynamic and can have just 1 value e.g. `const array1 = ["124542"];` and can have any number of values.

I have tried using Ecma Script `reduce` and `map` methods.

```
const array2 = array1.map((value, index) => {
    return {
       comparableId: value,
       comparatorId: array1[index + 1] || '',
    };
});
```

Is there some other good way to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a for loop is probably the easiest here.

```js
const array1 = ["124542", "112244", "112245", "112246"];


const transform = (array) => {
  const result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i === 0 || i < array.length - 1; ++i) {
    result.push({
      comparableId: array[i],
      comparatorId: array[i + 1] ?? "",
    })
  }
  
  return result;
};

console.log(transform(array1));
console.log(transform(["124542"]));
```

Comment: try this for a single value in the array1 e.g. const array1=["124542"]; It will give an empty array result. For that, we need to have array2 = [ { "comparableId": "124542", "comparatorId": "" } ]

Comment: I've adjusted my answer. But it makes it easier and quicker to have all requirements in the question to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array1 = ["124542", "112244", "112245", "112246"];

let array2 = [];

array1.map((item, index) =>{
  
  array2.push({comparableId: item, comparatorId: array1[index+1] || ""})
})
console.log(array2)
```

Comment: try this for a single value in the array1 e.g. const array1=["124542"]; It will give an empty array result. For that, we need to have array2 = [
  {
    "comparableId": "124542",
    "comparatorId": ""
  }
]

Comment: already improved

Answer (score 0):

Fully declarative, no mutations solution.

```js
const
  array1 = ["124542", "112244", "112245", "112246"],
  array2 = [...Array(Math.ceil(array1.length / 2))].map((_, i) =>
    ({comparableId: array1[i * 2], comparatorId: array1[i * 2 + 1] ?? ""})
  );

console.log(array2);
```

Comment: some results are skipped, now.

Comment: What results?..

Answer (score 0):

A loop is the best option.

```js
const array1 = ["124542", "112244", "112245", "112246"]
let array2 = [];
for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i + 2) {
  array2[i] = {
    "comparableId": array2[i],
    "comparatorId": array2[i + 1]
  }
  console.log(array2[i])
}
```

array2 won't be a `const` variable as it is going to be modified each loop. If you really need it to be a constant then you'll have to define a new constant like so: `const array3 = array2;` at the end of your code.

Comment: "array2 won't be a const variable"? Yes it should be const, and each loop array2.push({...})

Comment: @TAHERElMehdi Wouldn't `array2.push()` result in an error because the value is a const? it has to be variable so that it can be modified by .push